# Android: Draw a moveable and sizeable rectangle on ImageView(Or any other bitmap compatible widget) and crop the selected region

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas

I want to crop my image which is being displayed on an ImageView. How I want to go about it is that I want a re-sizable rectangle to be displayed on the image. That rectangle will have moveable corners (which I can drag around with touch) to increase/decrease its size. The image below illustrates a demo of something I would like to develop.

P. S. I am not quite sure how to phrase my question.
What I want:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/832/customcropbox.jpg/

Comment: Use the source code from this library: https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution I came up with after ample research was:

Extend `ImageView` to make my own custom view.

`@Override` `onDraw` method and do my custom drawing there in that method.

Implement `onTouchListener` on the view to get the touch events and process them according to their position.

e. g.

I checked whether the touch was in the radius of the anchor point circle I drew around the movable rectangle that I was drawing in my overriden `onDraw` method.

**Edit:**
I am sorry guys I don't have that piece of code anymore, I came here after a very long time otherwise would have loved to help you out.

Heartache.

Comment: I would love to see the code, i think I will be doing something similar.

Comment: Could you please provide the code for your problem? Even I am facing a similar problem!

Comment: Hello,Could you please provide code.I am also trying to achieve the same and not getting any proper solution. It will really be helpful.